# Replace some accented letters from word in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to replace some accented letters from Portuguese words in Python.

```
accentedLetters = ['à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'é', 'ê', 'í', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ú', 'ü']
letters         = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'u', 'u']
```

So the accentedLetters will be replaced by the letter in the letters array.

In this way, my expected results are for example:

```
ação    => açao
frações => fraçoes
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What's your python version? and what's wrong with your current code?

Comment: Are you getting an error? The wrong output? You just want your code "verified"? What is your question?

Comment: Regular expressions are overkill in this program- use python's `string.replace()` builtin- `i.e. word = word.replace(al, letters[i])`

Answer (score 5):

A simple translation dictionary should do the trick.  For each letter, if the letter is in the dictionary, use its translation.  Otherwise, use the original.  Join the individual characters back into a word.

```
def removeAccents(word):
    repl = {'à': 'a', 'á': 'a', 'â': 'a', 'ã': 'a',
            'é': 'e', 'ê': 'e',
            'í': 'i',
            'ó': 'o', 'ô': 'o', 'õ': 'o',
            'ú': 'u', 'ü': 'u'}

    new_word = ''.join([repl[c] if c in repl else c for c in word])
    return new_word
```

Comment: `repl = [` shouldn't that be `repl = {`?

Comment: That is not working for me. However, I found a way of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the Unidecode library for Python3.

For example:

```
from unidecode import unidecode

a = ['à', 'á', 'â', 'ã', 'é', 'ê', 'í', 'ó', 'ô', 'õ', 'ú', 'ü']

for k in a:
    print (unidecode(u'{0}'.format(k)))
```

Result:

a
a
a
a
e
e
i
o
o
o
u
u

Answer (score 0):

I have finally solved my problem:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys

def removeAccents(word):
    replaceDict = {'à'.decode('utf-8'): 'a', 
                   'á'.decode('utf-8'): 'a',
                   'â'.decode('utf-8'): 'a',
                   'ã'.decode('utf-8'): 'a',
                   'é'.decode('utf-8'): 'e',
                   'ê'.decode('utf-8'): 'e',
                   'í'.decode('utf-8'): 'i',
                   'ó'.decode('utf-8'): 'o',
                   'ô'.decode('utf-8'): 'o',
                   'õ'.decode('utf-8'): 'o',
                   'ú'.decode('utf-8'): 'u',
                   'ü'.decode('utf-8'): 'u'}

    finalWord = ''
    for letter in word:
        if letter in replaceDict:
            finalWord += replaceDict[letter]
        else:
            finalWord += letter
    return finalWord


word = (sys.argv[1]).decode('utf-8')
print removeAccents(word)
```

This just works as I expected.

Comment: Using `+=` to concat string is not very efficient. Better use `''.join(finalChars)` where `finalChars` starts as `[]` and collects the letters.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option using regex:

```
import re

def remove_accents(string):
    if type(string) is not unicode:
        string = unicode(string, encoding='utf-8')

    string = re.sub(u"[àáâãäå]", 'a', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[èéêë]", 'e', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[ìíîï]", 'i', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[òóôõö]", 'o', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[ùúûü]", 'u', string)
    string = re.sub(u"[ýÿ]", 'y', string)

    return string
```